# SSHguard: Does one to change any configuration for basic usage of the program?

Tags: linux, brute-force, ubuntu, configuration

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I've installed *SSHGuard* (`sudo apt-get install sshguard -y`) to protect from Brute Force Attacks (BFAs) on whatever user.

From reading about the program in [ArchLinux wikipedia](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sshguard) and in the [SSHguard website](https://www.sshguard.net/), it is unclear to me if one needs to add/change **any** *SSHguard* configuration, to enjoy its basic functionality, in **Ubuntu/Debian** distros in particular (one user told me something like "just install and use").

By "basic usage" I mean: Have protection from SSH brute force attacks of whatever user of a given system, per the **default** *SSHguard* rules.

Does one have to change any configuration for basic usage of the program?

Comment: Hi, you want to assign a bounty for this question? It is likely because you answered it yourself. Try deleting your answer (it seems to not be an answer anymore).

Comment: Yes, I've deleted the question and fully refreshed the page but still isn't possible " `question eligible for bounty since 2 days ago`" instead "`start a bounty`".

Answer (score 1):

I've manually verified this trying to login to my remote machine and it seems that SSHguard works OOB (Out Of Box), without me changing anything in the configuration:

Indeed, after 6 tries, I got a Putty fatal error, with this message:

> Server sent disconnect message type 2 (protocol error): "Too many
>   authentication failures"

### Update

I likely was wrong and it comes from Putty. Will further test later.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I didn't see in your initial post that you read the Arch Wiki. To answer your question, yes you can "just install and use". Below are the relevant excerpts from the wiki.

Out of the box SSHguard should provide basic protection, but there may be some things you want to configure such as Danger Level.

"Offenders become permanently banned once they reach a "danger" level of 120 (or 12 failed logins; see attack dangerousness for more details). This behavior can be modified by prepending a danger level to the blacklist file.

> BLACKLIST_FILE=200:/var/db/sshguard/blacklist.db

The 200: in this example tells sshguard to permanently ban a host after achieving a danger level of 200."

Also, if you are using UFW, you need to pass along DROP control to sshguard. I can't figure out how to format the block of code, so I'll post this link to the arch wiki with it.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sshguard